# Java generics - mixing types allowed?

Tags: java, generics

I was running some tests earlier and could not find an explanation as to why this code does what it does:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(Double.valueOf(0.1234)));
        System.out.println(list.get(0)); //prints 0.1234
        Object d = list.get(0);
        System.out.println(d.getClass()); // prints class java.lang.Double
        System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass()); // ClassCastException
    }
}
```

That raises a few questions:

- why does the List<Integer> accept a Double in the first place (should it compile at all)?

  why does the second print work and not the third, although it looks like they are doing the same thing?

EDIT
I understand the following 2 statements:

```
List aList = new ArrayList(); //I can add any objects in there
List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //I can only add something that extends Integer in there
```

But I don't understand why this one is authorised and why it actually works to some extent at runtime although some operations produce a ClassCastException - I would have expected a ClassCastException at the first line of the code posted above:

```
List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList(); //I can any objects in there
```

Comment: on your edit: That works so java versions from before generics are still supported. (Java puts lots of effort into being backwards compatible.)

Comment: after some thought I modified my answer below. I think it now answers more precisely on why that works the way it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write

```
... new ArrayList<Integer>(...
```

instead it will cause a compiler exception.

On why it works:

```
System.out.println(list.get(0)); //prints 0.1234
```

The method `Object.toString()` is the same in `Double` and `Integer` (And because `System.out.println()` expects an Object this is not cast into an `Integer` (the compiler optimized the cast away))

```
Object d = list.get(0);
System.out.println(d.getClass()); // prints class java.lang.Double
```

Same goes for `.getClass()`. Here the optimizer again dropped the cast.

```
System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass()); // ClassCastException
```

This actually creates an `Integer` from the list and that fails. It does the cast because the optimizer thought it need to do it, because its not obvious that it doesn't need to.

If you would change that last line to:

```
    System.out.println(((Object)list.get(0)).getClass());
```

it works :)

Comment: So list.get(0) is cast to Object and the 2nd print statement works but list.get(0) in list.get(0).getClass() is cast to Integer and that fails in the 3rd print statement.

Comment: @assylias basically yes but you must understand that the parts that work do so just because of compiler optimization. A class cast has a cost and when the compiler sees its unnecessary (because a Object is explicitly requested) it just drops it.

Comment: @assylias If you add (Object) in the last line it works as well (see my again edited answer. Here also the compiler strips the cast away so no ClassCastException is thrown.

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(Double.valueOf(0.1234)))
```

creates a raw (untyped) `ArrayList`, in to which you can place anything.  This is the correct way to do it:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Double.valueOf(0.1234)))
```

which should now not compile.

Comment: I know about the correct form. I am just curious as to why the code I posted compiles although it is declared as a List &lt;Integer&gt; and why it sends a ClassCastException at runtime for some operations and not others.

Comment: So is this a hole in the compiler, allowing you to put an `ArrayList` in an `ArrayList<Integer>`? Or is it allowed for a reason?

Comment: @Toomai: It's to support legacy code, before generics were introduced.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure.

Comment: Also it should be noted, that compiling the original program produces a warning about an unchecked call on the line where `list` is assigned value. Basically, if you use generics, your code is guaranteed not to throw a `ClassCastException` **only if everything compiles without any warnings about unchecked casts**.

Comment: Basically you have to remember that in Java all generics are just X<Object> where the compiler adds the appropriate casting. So if you create an `ArrayList<Integer>` it is still just an old-style `ArrayList` of objects, that the compiler puts casts around for you. So you can create an `ArrayList<Integer>` cast or assign it to an `ArrayList<Object>` and treat it as such just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The second one does not work because when you use generics the compiler inserts the casts for you (you don't have to). The compiler tries to cast the element to Integer because that is the generic type of the list.

Because you added to the list via an unchecked add, something is now in the list that was not checked when it was going in, thus it fails on coming out.